# POSTGRESQL Database Triggers anf functions

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in postgres that if you are trying to add an existing id within a customers table it will raise an error and won't allow you to do it.

Trigger Code:

```
create trigger id_check() 
before insert on customers 
for each row execute procedure duplicates()
```

Function:

```
create or replace function duplicates() 
returns trigger as  $BODY$ 
begin 
if exists(select 1 from customers where id = new.id) 
then raise notice 'cannot have a duplicate id' 
return new; 
end; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I keep getting errors either and I'm not understanding what's wrong? Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi isaac. Wouldn't a `unique constraint` suffice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated a [unique constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) is the appropriate method to properly handle this. But if you insist on your trigger then then you must cleanup the syntax errors: need semi-colon after raise statement, and end if at conclusion of IF. Also, learn now to format your code.

```
 create or replace function duplicates() 
    returns trigger as  $BODY$ 
    begin 
        if exists(select 1 from customers where id = new.id) 
           then raise notice 'cannot have a duplicate id';     --- added ;
        end if;                                                --- added line

        return new; 
   end; 
    $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```